# Why is master-slave replication in mongoDB deprecated? How is a replica set better?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

What are reasons to choose a replica set over master-slave replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to providing all the functionality of master-slave deployments, replica sets are also more robust for production use.

Master-slave replication preceded replica sets and made it possible to have a large number of non-master (i.e. slave) nodes, as well as to restrict replicated operations to only a single database; however, master-slave replication provides less redundancy and does not automate fail over.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
 **Why you should use replica set over master-slave replication?**

Answer: 
**A) Automated handling of failures** - In situations where the master node has failed in the Master-Slave replication you would have to perform manual actions like connecting to one of the slaves and restart it as a master. 
 Replica-set provides this out of the box and one of the secondaries will be automatically elected as a new primary.

**B) Automated Recovery** - In the Master-Slave replication the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) exist only on the master so in case of failures you would have to re-create it on the new master and then sync all other slaves to it. 
Replica-set handle oplogs differently and save you this extra administration effort.

---

Question 2:
 **When to use each one of the deployment strategies?**

Answer:
**When you can.** 
Replica-Set can be considered as the next-generation of Master-Slave strategy so it should provide you with all the capabilities that the old Master-Slave architecture gave.
With addition to that, **since MongoDB 3.6 master-slave replication is deprecated**.

The only situation where I can think of that Master-Slave is preferred (beside when running on legacy systems) is when you have more then 50 replica nodes in the architecture - This is the top limit of Replica Set at least as mentioned [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15060).